# Hibernate one-to-one mapping - Insert/update using existing foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I'm getting below error while trying to insert record to my table.

Here is hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.pojo.Child" table="SOME_SCHEMA.CHILD" lazy="true">
    <id name="primKey" column="ID" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">pr</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="isAllowed" column="IS_ALLOWED"/>
    <property name="ts" column="UPDATE_TS"/>
    <one-to-one name="pr" class="com.pojo.Parent" constrained="true"/>
</class>
```

My entity objects: Parent.java contains all the getter and setter of Parent table.
Child.java contains "id" as integer, "pr" as instance variable (to represent foreign table), getter and setter for IS_ALLOWED and UPDATE_TS.

Here is my code to insert record in CHILD table:

```
public List<Child> insertChildRecords(List<Child> childList, Timestamp timestamp) {

    List<Child> notInsertedList = null;

    final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    for (final Child  child : childList) {
        if (null !=  child) {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            try {
                    final Parent pr = new Parent();
                    pr.setStatusCode("AVAILABLE");
                    pr.setName("SURNAME");

                    child.setPr(pr);

                     child.setTS(timestamp);


                    session.saveOrUpdate( child);

                    transaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    if(null != transaction) {
                        transaction.rollback();
                    }
                } catch (HibernateException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Rollback exception:" +e.getMessage());
                }
                LOGGER.error("Exception: "
                        + ex.getMessage());
                 LOGGER.error( child.toString());
                if (null == notInsertedList) {
                    notInsertedList = new ArrayList<Child>();
                }
                notInsertedList.add(child);
            }
        }
    }
    return propListNotInserted;
}
```

My concern here is, I'm not supposed to create any record in PARENT table. I'm just using Parent id and trying to insert into Child using that id. To retrieve the parent id, I have set various parameters (which I assume is equivalent to WHERE clause of a native SQL).

When I execute this piece of code, Hibernate throws exception for all the elements in the 'childList'.

```
Hibernate: insert into SOME_SCHEMA.CHILD (IS_ALLOWED, UPDATE_TS, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
TRACE type.StringType: binding 'N' to parameter: 1
type.TimestampType: binding '2016-06-29 15:04:10' to parameter: 2
TRACE type.IntegerType: binding '0' to parameter: 3


ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-530, SQLSTATE=23503, SQLERRMC=SOME_SCHEMA.CHILD.FK_CHILD_PARENT_01, DRIVER=3.62.56

ERROR def.AbstractFlushingEventListener: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.pojo.Child]
```

The main problem I figured is, Hibernate is not trying to fetch the ID from Parent based on what I have set; rather assigns '0' to Child ID.

How do I solve this?

Thanks for all your answers in advance, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not supposed to create any record in PARENT table. I'm just using Parent id and trying to insert into Child using that id.

Then why are you having this code?

```
final Parent pr = new Parent();
```

If you want to assign an existing Parent to the Child class you are creating, then you need to look it up and then assign it to Child.

Comment: I agree, but all I'm trying to see is, if I can avoid a trip to DB to look up for parent id. Cannot I handoff that job to Hibernate or DB layer to do it? In native SQL, I can simply write INSERT with sub select query and look up of id is done in DB layer.